# What's the difference between "migration:create" and "migration:generate"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've run help command on sequelize and saw that there are two different commands with the same description:

```
$ sequelize help:migration:create

Sequelize [Node: 6.9.5, CLI: 2.5.1, ORM: 3.8.0, mysql: 2.5.0]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development".
COMMANDS
    sequelize migration:create   -- Generates a new migration file.
    sequelize migration:generate -- Generates a new migration file.
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference: `migration:generate` is alias for `migration:create`

https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/lib/tasks/migration.js#L20